# Electric guitar output not working

Tags: arduino, audio, gain, arduino-uno, guitar-pedal

So I (foolishly) decided to try and build an effects pedal of sorts for an electric guitar. I'm running it through an Arduino, and the signal is received by the Arduino just fine, although I had to add gain (2.5 V) to the circuit as the ADC input pins on the Arduino can't read negative voltages.

This has all worked fine, until, upon attempting to output through my (admittedly basic) DAC (which was essentially just resistors leading from port D on the Arduino), only one tone is produced. I believe this is due to the output being only positive voltage when my headphones use positive and negative voltage to play sound (from my understanding of how they work).

So I believe if I can subtract a flat 2.5 V from my circuit, it will play sound correctly and my question is, is there a way to do that? I've tried Googling and I found nothing so I thought I would try asking here.

Comment: Could you add schematic and code to your question, please?

Comment: If a *tone* is being produced, you've misdiagnosed the problem. Something's wrong elsewhere.

Comment: The pickups on a guitar have a relatively weak output but I imagine the Arduino isn't putting too much of a load on it... one option is to run the offset voltage through the base of a transistor and out at the emitter you should have a clean signal running closer to 0V.

Comment: Probably a seres capacitor on the output, but I need to see a circuit diagram before committing an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since most guitar pedals run off of 9 V anyways, the op-amps inside run off of the GND and +9 V rail. This requires the input signal to be offset to 1/2 VCC, or 4.5 V.

Take a look at this Boss OD-1 schematic snippet and see how an NPN transistor is used in the final path of the circuit to take the 4.5 V biased audio signal back down to the original input voltage, now with the effect applied.

[image]

This is the analog way of doing things, but you could probably adapt this exact circuit to the output of your pedal.

Comment: Actually it is not the emitter follower that is removing the 2.5 volts. It is the capacitor.